# SQL: how to update one table with the data from another using join in MariaDB

Tags: sql, join, mariadb

I am pretty new to SQL. I am trying to update one table with the data from another.

Table1: **albums**

```
album_id
user_id   -   correct value
```

Table2: **images**

```
image_id
album_id
user_id  -  wrong value
```

I need to update
`images.user_id` with data from `albums.user_id` where `albums.album_id = images.album_id`

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `update`/`join`:

```
update images i join
       albums a
       using (album_id)
     set i.user_id = a.user_id;
```

Comment: it works! thank you! Just tiny typo its `i.user_id` instead of `i.userS_id`